# mysql command not executing using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

For some reason my sql query is not executing and the error message is not printing in php.  Here is the code:

```
    mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
    mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

    $sql = "DELETE FROM data WHERE id='".$_GET['id']."'";
    echo $sql;
    $result=mysql_db_query($sql);
    if(!$result) {
        $msg = "ERROR: ". mysql_error();
        echo $msg;
    }
```

I know its vulnerable for sql injection right now but im going to fix that after i get it working.  Also, if i copy what $sql prints and paste it into phpmyadmin it works and it does go into the if statement.

Comment: Do you have PHP error-reporting enabled?

Comment: mysql_db_query() is a depreciated function.

Comment: Have you activated display_errors and ajusted your error_reporting level?

Comment: also, the first argument of mysql_db_query is supposed to be the database connection, not the query.

Comment: `foo.php?id=' OR 1=1` -- I just deleted all records in your `data` table.  Please read up on [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), then go learn [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: Use `mysql_query()` and let us know what error are you getting - PHP, SQL or something else.

Comment: thanks, had to change the error reporting.  And I know it is vulnerable to sql injections, I was just getting it to work first.

Comment: come on Charles, the OP mentioned that he is aware of SQL injection, so what's your point?

Answer (score 2):

You want to use [mysql_query()](http://php.net/mysql_query), not mysql_db_query().

And why do you enclose all your variables in quotes?

Answer (score 1):

Use `mysql_query()` instead of `mysql_db_query()` which is deprecated.

Comment: i was using mysql_query() and it wasn't working so i tried out mysql_db_query() out of desperation and just forgot to swith it back before posting.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-db-query.php

```
mysql_db_query

This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.
```

instead use mysql_query